# Why these variables not getting recognized?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I have a class called as movie Catalog and trying to return the list of this class from another class however the variables, name, desc and rating is not getting recognized.

@RestController
   @RequestMapping("/catalog")
   public class MovieCatalogResource {

```
@RequestMapping("/{userId}")    
public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String 
userId){


return Collections.singletonList(
            new CatalogItem(name: "Transformer", desc:"Test", rating:4)
            );
  }
}
```

Following is an error.

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ":", invalid 
     AssignmentOperator
    - desc cannot be resolved to a variable

I have got all the packages correctly imported and they have the references

I am looking for the code compilation however because these variables are not getting recognized it is failing.

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use named parameters, which Java does not support.

If the constructor for `CatalogItem` looks like this: `CatalogItem(String name, String desc, int rating)` you call it like this: `new CatalogItem("Transformer", "Test", 4);`